# Upgrade to v3.8.0 but still showing "Welcome to the JHipster Generator v3.3.0"

Tags: jhipster, yo

I have performed

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

with and without sudo on my ubuntu machine but it keeps showing

**Welcome to the JHipster Generator v3.3.0** and
**JHipster update available: 3.8.0 (current: 3.3.0)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the update command, or installing at the specific version.

```
npm update -g generator-jhipster

npm install -g generator-jhipster@3.8.0
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

Working now, I think a local copy was hiding global one

I did following

npm update generator-jhipster

npm install  generator-jhipster@3.8.0